# How to setState via Axios Post in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, stripe-payments

using react and node, i'm writing a stripe payment processor to setState clientSecret via axios post request. the backend's returned result (ie value for clientSecret) is fine. my problem lies in the frontend: not being able to update the state despite being able to output the success message via console.log. i've written several renditions, but they boil down to two examples, neither of which work but which i've pasted below:

**example1.js**

```
..
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clientSecret: ''
    };
  }

  async componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.cartItems !== prevProps.cartItems) {
      const data = {cart_items2: this.props.cartItems};
      var self = this;
      await axios.post('/create-payment-intent', data)
      .then(result => {
        console.log('Success in creating payment intent');
        self.result = result.data;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error in creating payment intent', err);
      })
      if(this.result) {
        this.setState({clientSecret: this.result.clientSecret}, () => { 
          console.log("this.state.clientSecret is", this.state.clientSecret);
        });
      }
    }
  }
..
```

**example2.js**

```
import PaymentForm from './PaymentForm.js';
import OrderSummary from './OrderSummary.js';
import { Elements, ElementsConsumer } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';
import './checkout.css';
import axios from 'axios';
const React = require('react');

class Payment extends React.Component {
..
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      clientSecret: ''
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.cartItems !== prevProps.cartItems) {
      const data = {cart_items2: this.props.cartItems};
      axios.post('/create-payment-intent', data)
      .then(result => {
        if(result.data) {
          console.log('Success in creating payment intent');
          this.setState({clientSecret: result.data.clientSecret}, () => { 
          console.log("this.state.clientSecret is", this.state.clientSecret);
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Error in creating payment intent', err);
      })
    }
  }
..
render() {
    
    return (
      <div>
      <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
      <ElementsConsumer>
      {({ stripe, elements }) => (
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column">
            <PaymentForm stripe={stripe} elements={elements}/>
          </div>
          <div class="column">
            <OrderSummary cartItems={this.props.cartItems}/>
          </div>
        </div>

      )}
      </ElementsConsumer>
      </Elements>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default Payment;
```

Comment: The second example is how you do it. In the first example, the setState runs before the code in the `then` block. Are you sure result.data.clientSecret is not empty?

Comment: @windowsill confirmed too many times result.data.clientSecret is not empty

Comment: What does `console.log("this.state.clientSecret is", this.state.clientSecret);` output? Is this where the problem lies? Or is it somewhere else? What does logging `result.data` output?

Comment: @g0rb this console.log does not even run suggesting to me the setState never gets triggered

Comment: Try using react functional components rather than class based components, it has better and easier syntax

Comment: @femtowatts interesting.. but 'Success in creating payment intent' is logged?

Answer (score 0):

there's a possibility that your app is consuming the `clientSecret` when it's not yet ready. Can you share the complete code and show us how you use the `clientSecret` in your frontend app?

Comment: code updated in example2; i'm roughly transitioning the code piece by piece towards class component after a functional component found here https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart

Comment: So this.state.clientSecret is never used in your code??